# How to rotate text 90 degrees inline

Tags: css, rotation, text-rotation

How do I rotate text 90 degrees without using the style sheet? I have placed the following instruction in the header area of the page:

```
<style>
div.rotate-text {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>
```

Then I placed the following around the paragraph in question.

```
<div id="rotate-text">
<p>My paragraph</p>
</div>
```

But its not working and hence my question.

Comment: Your css selector is wrong: it should be `div#rotate-text` and not `div.rotate-text`. `.` is for a class, `#` is for an id.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a small visual example:

```css
#rotate-text {
   width: 25px;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate-text">
  <p>My paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: should I wrap the header id information between <style></style> as I have done?

Comment: Yes, just set the CSS block in your `<style></style>` tag and that should work!

Answer (score 22):

You can use css property `writing-mode`

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl
```

or

```
writing-mode: vertical-lr
```

Or using transform property: rotate

```
transform: rotate(90deg)
```

Comment: ya, writing mode is what i wanted! I wanted to rotate the long headers in a table so they wouldn't take up as much space.

Answer (score 5):

you use of `id` in html code, so you must use of `#` in css.

**Change:**

```
div.rotate-text {
```

**To:**

```
div#rotate-text {
```

```css
div#rotate-text {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 100px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate-text">
  <p>My paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Writing mode is better for text content, with transform: rotate() the text container still stays with the horizontal dimensions.

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl; //Rotate -90deg
writing-mode: vertical-lr; //Rotate 90deg
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the text reading from the bottom up, use this:

```css
#rotate-text {
   writing-mode: vertical-lr;
   transform: scale(-1, -1);
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate-text">
  <p>My paragraph</p>
</div>
```